# Is single-word form submission a known attack?

Tags: security

I have one website that is consistently getting weird form submissions. It's a contact form that captures name, email, subject, and message. Five to ten times per day it gets a submission where all the fields are filled in, the name and the email appear to be real, but unrelated (e.g., "Tom Jones", and "bob_smith@<major_email_provider>.com), and the subject and message are each one (apparently) random word (e.g., today, one had the subject "infrastructure" and the message "Ball").

Is this some known "attack" (I put that in quotations since at only 5-10 per day, it's clearly not a DOS or something)? Should I care about it? Should I do something about it?

Comment: Possible, but also possibly unlikely. How is the form protected? Do you have a Captcha on it? Does the processing script protect against direct submissions (i.e. post data from external sources that didn't come from a genuine form submission)?

Comment: It does have Captcha (v3). I ... don't know about direct submissions. It's a Contact Form 7 form in WordPress, and I'm not sure how they handle that under the covers.

Comment: OK, that's a fairly robust contact form plugin (it's perhaps **the** go-to contact form fr WP).